# Ms access - Disable tabbed (sub)form until main form's ID is not null

Tags: ms-access

I have a main form (frmCustomer) bound to tblCustomers, and a tabbed subform with 2 pages, one bound to tblCustomerAddress and the other to tblContacts.

I don't want the user to be able to insert data in the tabbed form, until I have a valid CustomerID.

I tried (on current event of main form, before update)
If isNull(Me.CustomerID) then
     Me.Page_Address.Enabled = False
end if
But it disables the tabbed form and keeps it disabled forever...

Thank you so much for any thoughts as I am clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as the Current event, perhaps need to put code in another event, such as AfterUpdate of first control on main form that gets data input.

Then instead of If Then, simply

`Me.Page_Address.Enabled = True`

or

`Me.Page_Address.Enabled = Not IsNull(Me.CustomerID)`

Comment: I had tried to put such code on the after update of customer id, which is automatically generated, to no avail but, following your suggestion to put the code on the first control that gets input, that works!